# Why query statement results on eloquent orm is returning null values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm new to this questions thing so please bear with me.

I'm using Eloquent as my PHP database library. So I created a class that extends from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and tried to query one single record. When I print the results I know it is fetching the information, as you can see by the protected *attributes*, but somehow the public attributes of the record are NULL.

Am I missing some previous configuration, or is there another reason for that?

Here's my structure:

The Model, `Plantilla.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Plantilla extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_plantilla';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'plantilla';
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    public function __construct()
    {
        #attributes
        parent::__construct();
        Database2::init();
    }
}
```

`Database.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class Database2
{
    private static $db;

    static public function init()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$db)) {
            $capsule = new Capsule;

            $capsule->addConnection([
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
                'database' => getenv('DB_NAME'),
                'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
                'password' => getenv('DB_PASS'),
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
            ], 'mysql');

            // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
            $capsule->setAsGlobal();

            // Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
            $capsule->bootEloquent();
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```php
$p = Plantilla::where('cod_plantilla', 35)->first();
var_dump($p);
```

Result

```
object(App\Models\Plantilla)[251]
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'cod_plantilla' (length=13)
  protected 'table' => string 'plantilla' (length=9)
  protected 'connection' => string 'mysql' (length=5)

  # Values I need
  public 'cod_area_interna' => null
  public 'cod_tipo_plantilla' => null
  public 'nombre' => null
  public 'detalle' => null
  public 'personalizada' => null
  public 'fecha' => null
  # Values I need

  protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'withCount' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false

  # Same values I need but they're protected
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=7)
      'cod_plantilla' => int 35
      'cod_area_interna' => int 2
      'cod_tipo_plantilla' => int 1
      'nombre' => string 'Some' (length=32)
      'detalle' => string 'Some' (length=142)
      'personalizada' => null
      'fecha' => string '2020-06-25 12:15:13' (length=19)
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=7)
      'cod_plantilla' => int 35
      'cod_area_interna' => int 2
      'cod_tipo_plantilla' => int 1
      'nombre' => string 'Some' (length=32)
      'detalle' => string 'Some' (length=142)
      'personalizada' => null
      'fecha' => string '2020-06-25 12:15:13' (length=19)
  protected 'changes' => 
...
```

As the documentation states, you can do something like this

```php
<?php

$flights = App\Models\Flight::all();

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

So you can access the attributes aka table columns values.

In my case those are:

- cod_plantilla
- cod_area_interna
- cod_tipo_plantilla
- nombre
- detalle
- personalizada
- fecha

Comment: Welcome to SO ... there is no 'public' attributes, the attributes array is 'protected' ... there are multiple ways to access these attributes on the model though ... what are you actually looking for at the moment?

Comment: i don't understand what your question is actually asking ... you have a model instance, not `null`, that is the representation of the record from your table, the fields are the attributes ... do you not know how to access the attributes of the model?

Comment: I edited the cuestion so it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are actually asking about here.

The attributes are not 'properties' of the class. They are held in a protected array named `$attributes`. If you want to access them you can do that in the way the documentation says you can.

You could access them via the dynamic property:

```
$p = Plantilla::find(35);

echo $p->nombre;
```

Via array access:

```
echo $p['nombre'];
```

You can get the array of attributes themselves:

```
dump($p->getAttributes());
```

Serialize the model's attributes (and loaded relationships) to an array:

```
dump($p->toArray());
```

Or even get the serialized model as JSON:

```
echo $p->toJson();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using the $p->nombre returns *null* value but if I use the $p['nombre'] it returns the expected value.
Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Eloquent is actually performing exactly as it should be!

Eloquent does a lot of automagic with PHP magic methods. What *looks* like regular PHP object properties are actually dynamically accessed via `__get()` and `__set()` from the `$attribute` property.

In your example you have this:

```
$p = Plantilla::where('cod_plantilla', 35)->first();
```

Using Tinker (if you're new to Laravel, it's easiest to use `php artisan tinker` to figure out this sort of stuff), you should be able to just try accessing your database columns like this:

```
> $p->cod_plantilla;
35
> $p->fecha;
'2020-06-25 12:15:13'
```

You should find your values are returned, even though `var_dump()` shows nothing!